# Python - prime numbers

Tags: python, python-2.7, primes

I am creating a program in python which adds up the total of all the prime numbrs up to 10. My code so far is:

```
total = 0

for i in range (10):
    for a in range (2,i):
        if i % a == 0:
            break
        else:
            total += i
            break

print total
```

My code does not include 2 as a prime number but does include 9. Can anybody spot the error?

Comment: `a` will never be more than 2 because you always break immediately.

Comment: You should use continue instead of break

Comment: See my answer below, I believe it is just an indentation error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `else:` clause needs to be with the `for` loop not `if` statement and no `break`.
As pointed out 2 drops through immediately, which is perfectly okay as it is prime and the `else` clause is executed:

```
total = 0
for num in range(2, 10):      # Start from 2
    for i in range(2, num):
        if num%i==0:
            break             # Not prime, break causes else clause not to be executed
    else:
        total += num
print total
17
```

For very low numbers this will be fine, though you really only need to check to the sqrt of num.